# How to navigate in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I was trying the navigator.push but it didn't work. The code executed without errors but my emulator won't navigate when I push the button. I tried all the three methods, the direct navigation with materialrootpage, static navigation with route map, Dynamic Navigation with onGeneratedRoute

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'submit_id.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Bits mess'
          ,style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20,
              letterSpacing: 5

            ),),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),

        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
              Container(
                child: Image(
                  image: NetworkImage('https://www.google.com/maps/uv?pb=!1s0x3bbfb9a68009cf11%3A0x312ca93e696b7ee0!3m1!7e115!4shttps%3A%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipNjLLtffoDS_xSU6ZBOflCueMzOhW_10s6udnm0%3Dw162-h108-n-k-no!5smess%20food%20-%20Google%20Search!15sCgIgAQ&imagekey=!1e10!2sAF1QipNjLLtffoDS_xSU6ZBOflCueMzOhW_10s6udnm0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuw4HCwsn6AhWc9DgGHWgYCJoQ7ZgBKAF6BAgSEAM#',
                      scale:0.6 ),
                )
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 140,width: 12),
              Container(
                //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 60,horizontal: 150),
                //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.5,vertical: 0.5),
                child: SizedBox
                    (width: 300,
                    height: 70,
```

in this widget I used the navigator widget

```
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Submitid())
                        );
                        },
                        child: Text('Submit ID')),
```

Ignore from here if you want to

```
                )),
                SizedBox(height: 70,width: 10),
                Container(
                 //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 60,horizontal: 150),
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.5,vertical: 0.5),

                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 70,
                    child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('Get ID'),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
                    )),
                  ),
                SizedBox(height: 50,width: 10),
                ]
              ),
        )
      )
      );

  }
}
```

The screen I want to navigate to

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Submitid extends StatefulWidget {
  const Submitid({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Submitid> createState() => _SubmitidState();
}

class _SubmitidState extends State<Submitid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Bits mess'
            ,style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20,
                letterSpacing: 5

            ),),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),


      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add print in onPressed to check the press function is working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your Scaffold widget in MaterialApp to reach different context. You can extract your Scaffold into a class:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bits mess',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20,
            letterSpacing: 5

        )),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        centerTitle: true,
    ),

    body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
          Container(
            child: Image(
              image: NetworkImage('https://www.google.com/maps/uv?pb=!1s0x3bbfb9a68009cf11%3A0x312ca93e696b7ee0!3m1!7e115!4shttps%3A%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipNjLLtffoDS_xSU6ZBOflCueMzOhW_10s6udnm0%3Dw162-h108-n-k-no!5smess%20food%20-%20Google%20Search!15sCgIgAQ&imagekey=!1e10!2sAF1QipNjLLtffoDS_xSU6ZBOflCueMzOhW_10s6udnm0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuw4HCwsn6AhWc9DgGHWgYCJoQ7ZgBKAF6BAgSEAM#',
                  scale:0.6 ),
            )
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 140,width: 12),
          Container(
            //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 60,horizontal: 150),
            //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.5,vertical: 0.5),
            child: SizedBox
                (width: 300,
                height: 70,
                

                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () =>
                    Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => Submitid()))
                    ,
                    child: Text('Submit ID')),


            )),
            SizedBox(height: 70,width: 10),
            Container(
             //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 60,horizontal: 150),
              //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.5,vertical: 0.5),

              child: SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                height: 70,
                child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Get ID'),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(),
                )),
              ),
            SizedBox(height: 50,width: 10),
            ]
          ),
    )
  );
 }
}
```

And call this widget in your MaterialApp:

```
MaterialApp(
  home: Home(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
)
```